# Can we unload data from redshift to different S3 folders based on a field

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, unload

I have a 100 weeks(week 1 to 100) of data and i want to load this into 52 different folders.
This is the file path i desire:

File path 100 : Week 100 - Week (100-52)

File path 99 : Week 99 - Week (99-52)

.

.

.

File path 53 : Week 53 - Week (53-52)

I want to do all this preferably using a single unload.

Comment: To do this use case, you can use the AWS SDK and write the logic using both the Amazon S3 API and Redshift API.

Answer (score 0):

You can partition an UNLOAD - see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Comment: Partitioning an unload will just split it into files based on one date. But i want to do is add 52 weeks of data in each file path. 2 files paths WILL have overlapping  data. Partition by date will not achieve it

Comment: So it sounds like partitioning the UNLOAD is not your concern but rather generating the data you want to unload.  If you can generate the data that has "partition" as a column unloading by this column is not the issue, right?  OK to help with the SQL you need you will need to define the process better.  What does "Week 100 - Week (100-52)" mean?  Is this row ranges or subtraction?  Is it subtraction of rows or values?  You will need to provide detail and examples of how you expect the data to be separated and duplicated.